# Given a nonzero vector $B$ and a vector-valued function $F$ such that $F(t)\cdot B=t$ for all $t$, show that$F''$ is orthogonal to $F'$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Given a nonzero vector $B$ and a vector-valued function $F$ such that $F(t)\cdot B=t$ for all $t$, and such that the angle between $F'(t)$ and $B$ is constant (independent of $t$). Prove that $F''(t)$ is orthogonal to $F'(t)$.

What I have so far is that $F'(t)\cdot B+F(t)\cdot B'=1$, so $F'\cdot B=1$. I need to show $F''\cdot F'=0$. But how do I get here from what I have? I would appreciate any solutions or hints.

Comment: Take more derivatives!

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I've tried but I don't see where it gets me...

Comment: @takecare F' B = 1 is a key information here. Also, F' B = |F'| |B| cos(a), since the angle between F' and B is constant, cos(a) is constant. Now, |F'| = 1/(|B|)(cos(a)) since F' B = 1. We square both sides so, |F'|^2 = (1/(|B|)(cos(a)))^2 but |F'|^2 = F' F'. Differentiating both sides we have, 2F''F' = 0, hence F''F' = 0.